# Will the "Content Health" feature come to public Q&A on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, review, answer-quality, outdated-information

It was announced in *The Overflow* today there's a new *Content Health* feature is being launched on Stack Overflow for Teams. Are there currently plans to introduce this to public Q&A sites on Stack Exchange? Or is that possibility at present still beyond the event horizon?

> [Introducing Content Health, a new way to keep the knowledge base up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/17/introducing-content-health-a-new-way-to-keep-the-knowledge-base-up-to-date/?cb=1)
>
> We will build upon and enhance this new feature over the months to come, but we’re excited to share with you an early version that Business plan customers on Stack Overflow for Teams can use immediately. Our Enterprise customers will get access to the feature with our upcoming 2021.3 release.

Comment: Also, could the blog be reworded? It's only in paragraph 3 that it finally mentions it only relates to SO for Teams and not the main product.